# C++ Excel::RangePtr - Expression must be a pointer to a complete object type

Tags: c++, excel, pointers, expression

My original module was based on [this tutorial](http://www.technical-recipes.com/2012/how-to-interface-with-excel-in-c/).
Basically I have a module that compiles fine and works fine, but IntelliSense pollutes the "Error List" View with false errors.

```
...

// Access Excel Worksheet and return pointer to Worksheet cells  
Excel::_WorksheetPtr pWksheet = pXL->ActiveSheet;  

pWksheet->Name = L"Sheet1";

Excel::RangePtr pRange = pWksheet->Cells;

// Read an Excel data cell. (Note Excel cells start from index = 1)
double value1 = pRange->Item[1][2]; //pRange, Error:  Expression must be a pointer to a complete object type
cout << "Value in CELL [1][2] = " << value1 << endl;

...
```

The false Intellise error in question occurs at this very last line, and

> pRange is underlined in red 
>   Error:  Expression must be a pointer to a complete object type

Any idea how to disable this error ?

Thanks very much in advance,
Minh